# Como extraer año, mes y día como, individual desde un dato DateTime, con dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta función pero me devuelve 2020/12/16, y quiero que me devuelta el año en tipo int 2020, el mes tipo int 12, y día tipo int 16.
este es mi código por favor a ver si me dais solución.La variable `fechIni` la traigo en String, por eso la he convertido en DateTime.

```
Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _groupEvents(List<Body> events) {
Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
events.forEach((event) {
  DateTime date = DateTime.parse(event.fechaIni);
  if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
  data[date].add(event);
});
return data;
```

}

Gracias de antemanos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca he utilizado Dart pero leyendo la [documentacion](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) encontre que `DateTime` tiene sus metodos `.year - .month - .day` que obtienes lo que quieres dando una fecha `YYY-MM-DD` con `-` y no con `/`.

Por ello una solucion que le di es reemplazar todos los `/` por `-` usando `replaceAll` de la siguiente manera y probado en [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?):

```
var fecha = '2020/12/16';
fecha = fecha.replaceAll('/', '-');
  
DateTime date = DateTime.parse(fecha);
print(date.year); //Año
print(date.month); //Mes
print(date.day); //Dia
```

Cabe resaltar que `year-month-day` devuelven `int` segun la documentacion

Otra solucion que encontre buscando es en instalar la libreria [intl-package](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)  para formatear la fecha y obtener los datos que quieres, de la siguiente manera:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy');
  final int formatted = formatter.format('2020/12/16');
  print(formatted); // 2013
}
```

Esto ultimo aun no lo he probado pero si saliera un error, en su documentacion esta mas detallado